# ¿Problema al sincronizar gradle a un proyecto Android por primera vez?

Tags: java, android, gradle

Lo primero que me dice mi ide cuando empiezo el proyecto es:

-------------------- NOTA --------------- -----
Gradle Wrapper no está disponible.
Instale uno predeterminado. Gradle v7.4 se descargará si es necesario.

Entonces empiezo a descargar algo y me sale un error.

```
Starting build...
 Creating Idea project model...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find gradle-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/7.2.1/gradle-7.2.1.jar
   > Could not find builder-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder:7.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder/7.2.1/builder-7.2.1.jar
   > Could not find sdklib-30.2.1.jar (com.android.tools:sdklib:30.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/sdklib/30.2.1/sdklib-30.2.1.jar
   > Could not find aapt2-proto-7.2.1-7984345.jar (com.android.tools.build:aapt2-proto:7.2.1-7984345).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/aapt2-proto/7.2.1-7984345/aapt2-proto-7.2.1-7984345.jar
   > Could not find builder-model-7.2.1.jar (com.android.tools.build:builder-model:7.2.1).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/builder-model/7.2.1/builder-model-7.2.1.jar
   > Could not find core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar (com.google.testing.platform:core-proto:0.0.8-alpha07).
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/testing/platform/core-proto/0.0.8-alpha07/core-proto-0.0.8-alpha07.jar

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

CONFIGURE FAILED in 26s
```

Voy a suponer que este error es debido a mi conexión a internet en ese caso hay una manera de descargar esas dependencias de manera manual o algo asi?

Comment: *Voy a suponer que este error es debido a mi conexión a internet*. ¿Por qué supones eso? ¿Tu conexión es lenta o no tienes conexión? Para la sincronización inicial necesitas internet, porque posiblemente sea necesario descargar algunas dependencias o incluso el mismo gradle o una nueva versión.

Comment: en tu seccion de repositorios agrega  `google()`, y si ya lo tienes edita tu pregunta para que tenga el archivo build

Comment: ¿Eso pasa con un proyecto recién creado sin modificaciones hechas por ti?

Answer (score 0):

Si no tienes dependencias y recursos necesarios para el proyecto, este no se podrá crear.

Debes asegurar tener conexión a internet y revisar que el "modo offline" no se encuentra activado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puede haber métodos para [descargar manualmente las dependencias y recursos](https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/manually-caching-and-finding-gradle-dependencies-made-easy-999f387661fa) necesarios para tu proyecto, pero lo ideal es que la IDE administre esta tarea, para esto es necesario contar con conexión a internet.